# The Content section goes over top the header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-image

I want to make something similar to this http://www.thomaspomarelle.com/ (custom design of course), but the problem I am encountering is that my about section which is supposed to be below the background picture and accessed by scrolling the page, goes on top of the header :( And I absolutely can't figure out why. I was thinking that is because I have the image in the body, but I tried putting the image in the div's after the header section, and it doesn't work at all. 
Here's my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>yudasinal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
   </head>

 <body id="backimage">
    <nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
          </div>
          <div id = "projects">
            <ul>
              <li class = "line">
                <a href = "#">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class = "line">
                <a href = "#">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class = "line">
                <a href = "#">HOME</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>  

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the css for it:

```
#projects ul {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#projects li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: top center; 
}

#projects ul li.line a {
    padding: 0 30px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#projects li.line a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 87%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

#projects li.line a:hover::after,
#projects li.line  a:focus::after {
    height: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}


#backimage {
    background-image: url(http://cs425729.vk.me/v425729136/4e67/6abwVXLTK9s.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

it also has twitter bootstrap css.

Thanks a lot for help in advance!!!

Comment: What's "about section" and what's "header section"? I can only see a `nav` element in the body. And there are many unclosed tags which makes the DOM a mess. You should get a new editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to get this same effect. I've found that html,body, and the div that holds your background image, needs a height of 100%. Best way I've found to do this. If anyone has a better way, please share.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b87pV/

### HTML

```
 <body>
 <div class="first">
     <div class="header">
         <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
         <nav>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
             </ul>   
         </nav>
      </div>
 </div>
 
<div class="second">
  <div id="projects">
  <h1>Projects</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi nesciunt explicabo ipsam laudantium quaerat dolorem molestiae. Reprehenderit, perspiciatis, assumenda, repellat dolores dolore corporis doloribus voluptatem magni suscipit aperiam fugiat quia.
    </p>    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 html,body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }    
    .first {
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(http://cs425729.vk.me/v425729136/4e67/6abwVXLTK9s.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .header {
        background: #333;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .logo, a {
        color: white;
    }
    .logo {
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    nav {
        float: right;
        padding: 5px
    }
    nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
    #projects {
        padding: 50px;
    }
```

I believe internet explorer trips up on background:cover. There are work arounds out there. Simple search away.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It works! :) 

Although I am still not sure why that option with div's or body didn't work.

Comment: Glad I could help! I find it helpful sometimes to reduce things to the essentials and work from there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I feel like I had a lot of unnecessary code there :) Now it's time to figure out other things!